# search from one sql table and insert into another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called places which has 2 million records. In these records there is a column called **city_name**.

In another table I have 2 columns: `city_name` and `city_id`.

My aim is to search the table cities with the `city_name` from the table places and insert the corresponding `city_id` from the table cities into the table places.

I have tried to use the following:

```
UPDATE places
INNER JOIN cities USING (city_name)
SET places.city_id = cities.city_id
```

The problem with this is that it has worked but i am having random city_id's in the `city_id` field that does not match the city name.

I should also mention that there might not be a corresponding city name in the table cities, so i want to ignore records that do not exist.

Can anyone help please. I am using phpmyadmin

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to provide same data and desired results to make it clear what you want to do.  You probably just need to fix your data.

Comment: ok what kind of data would you like me to provide ?

Comment: i think my code above does not actively search for matching city_name records but joins them in sync, as i have no search

Comment: some data which demonstrates the problem would make sense.

Comment: "search" is not a concept at the sql level. Use `cities left join places` to pick out only `places` rows that have a corresponding row in `cities`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly the solution would be

```
UPDATE places
SET places.city_id = (SELECT cities.city_id
                      FROM cities
                      WHERE cities.city_name = places.city_name)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the best logical solution and it seems to work a treat (although a little slow) but i will attribute the speed to a budget server.

Comment: Παρακαλώ Γιώργο. Μάρκαρε την απάντηση σαν αποδεκτή εάν σε βοήθησε.